# Using if... not in and a len() check isn't applying

Tags: python

I'm trying to add validation checks into my code here so that only the value `("A"), ("B") or ("C")` is allowed. If the `len()` part is removed, any string with the either of the three letters is allowed however if one of those letters are not used, it works as expected. When adding the `len()`, it seems to have no effect and just bypasses it even though the `len()` prints the correct value.

How do I resolve this?

Thanks!

```
classCheck = False
studentclass=input("What class are you in?\n A\n B\n C\n ")
print (len(studentclass))
while classCheck != True:
    if ("a" or "b" or "c") not in studentclass.lower() and len(studentclass) != 1:
        print ("You must enter a valid class")
        studentclass=input("What class are you in?\n A\n B\n C\n ")
    else:
        classCheck = True
```

Comment: `("a" or "b" or "c")` is simply equal to `"a"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do that:

```
classCheck = False
studentclass=input("What class are you in?\n A\n B\n C\n ")
print (len(studentclass))
while classCheck != True:
    if studentclass.lower() not in ['a', 'b', 'c']:
        print ("You must enter a valid class")
        studentclass=input("What class are you in?\n A\n B\n C\n ")
    else:
        classCheck = True
```

You solution did not work because Python does not speak english but Python so when you do :

```
("a" or "b" or "c") not in studentclass.lower()
```

It eval in the first time:

```
("a" or "b" or "c")
```

Which return the first expression with each such that bool(expr) == True so here it result in "a" then Python evaluate:

```
"a" not in studentclass.lower()
```

which is true for 'b' or 'c'

Answer (score 1):

I think you meant to use `if studentclass.lower() not in ["a", "b", "c"]`

Edit: Per comment(s) if you want a (negligible in this case) gain in speed use `("a", "b", "c")` assigning to a tuple is faster than a list.

Comment: Note (a micro-optimization to be sure), `not in ('a', 'b', 'c')` is *slightly* faster.